# Cartesian product- inner relations in table. SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, hierarchy, cartesian-product

I have a table built of two columns: person (text) and supervisor (text)- a sort of hierarchy table.

table name: hierarchy

| person | supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Alice |
| Mary | Susan |
| Alice | David |
| David | Mary |

I wish to create a third column that contains
the supervisors of the supervisors- "sup_supervisor"
example below:

| person | supervisor | sup_supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Alice | David |
| Mary | Susan |  |
| Alice | David | Mary |
| David | Mary | Susan |

Alice is the supervisor of Bob, and David is the supervisor of Alice. hence- David is the sup_supervisor.
notice that Mary does not have a sup_supervisor because Susan does not have a supervisor.

this is an example of a specific result- query (not what I need but has the general idea):
select supervisor from hierarchy
where person=(select supervisor from hierarchy where person = 'Bob'). this will give us Bob's sup_supervisor.

how do I create a query to generally create this column (not manually checking each time the relation)?

- bonus question:
  If I wish to implement this once again- after creating the third column, adding a fourth built of those who supervise the "sup_supervisor". will the concept be similar?

example: for Bob -> Alice -> David **-> Mary**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

that's not how to design relational tables. For a start, you should have primary key that is unique, just using the person's name means you can't handle 2 people with the same same.

If you want to reference another record (in the same or a different table) then you add a foreign key column that references the pk of the table being referenced